# Columns shift when SingleChildScrollView is added Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Need help. I have created a `column` on the page inside which there are 2 more `columns`, so I moved the buttons that are at the bottom to the very bottom so that they are always at the bottom of the screen. But when I add a `SingleChildScrollView` to make the page scroll, the space between the `columns` disappears and the bottom buttons move under other widgets. How can I solve the problem so that when adding a `SingleChildScrollView`, there is an empty space and the buttons remain at the very bottom of the screen?

**body**

```
Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                const SizedBox(height: 121.0),
                BackStepWidget(
                  text: 'Balance: $coins',
                  textStyle: constants.Styles.largeHeavyTextStyleWhite,
                ),
                const Text(
                  'Buy JoinCoins',
                  style: constants.Styles.bigHeavyTextStyleWhite,
                ),
                const Image(
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/image.png'),
                ),
                const Text('I Want To Buy',
                    style: constants.Styles.smallBoldTextStyleWhite),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                const CoinsCounterWidget(),
                const SizedBox(height: 10),
                const Text('JoynCoins',
                    style: constants.Styles.smallBoldTextStyleWhite),
              ],
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 24),
                  child: DefaultButtonGlow(
                    text: 'Buy me JoynCoins for 100% battery.',
                    color: constants.Colors.greyLight.withOpacity(0.4),
                    textStyle: constants.Styles.buttonTextStyle,
                    shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                    borderColor: constants.Colors.purpleMain,
                    onPressed: () {
                      showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (BuildContext context) {
                          return const DefaultAlertDialog(
                            text:
                                'Please set a payment method for buying JoynCoins.',
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 47),
                  child: DefaultButtonGlow(
                    text: 'Buy Now ',
                    color: constants.Colors.purpleMain,
                    textStyle: constants.Styles.buttonTextStyle,
                    shadowColor: constants.Colors.purpleMain,
                    borderColor: constants.Colors.purpleMain,
                    onPressed: () {
                      showDialog(
                          context: context,
                          builder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return const DefaultAlertDialog(
                              text: "You'r about to buy",
                              isText2: true,
                              text2: '2500 JoynCoins',
                            );
                          });
                    },
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ));
```

**Added SingleChildScrollView**

[image]

**Without SingleChildScrollView**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify this code to understand the issue. `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` will provide maximum spaces between widgets.

```dart
body: Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Text("top"),
    Text("bottom"),
  ],
),
```

[image]

Once you wrapped with  `SingleChildScrollView`,  `Column` takes minimum height for its children and become,

[image]

You can use `SizedBox` to provide space between items. You can use `LayoutBuidler` that I've posted on your previous question. For this I am using `MediaQuery`

```dart
body: SingleChildScrollView(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text("top"),
      SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .4,
      ), // you custom height
      Text("bottom"),
    ],
  ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you tell me what is the meaning of MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * .4 ? Why do you multiply by 4?

Answer (score 0):

Use SizedBox in between Columns or use the following inside Singlechildscrollview

```
physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
shrinkWrap: true,
```

Comment: If you add SizedBox() - it doesn't work. And shrinkWrap has no such method in SingleChildScrollView

Comment: SizedBox(height:100);